# Expanding list of li's with hidden content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a similar setup to the following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/d33zC/5/

divs in question:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle2('question', this);">Question</a>
    <div id="question" style="display:none; margin:0px;">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle2('question2', this);">Question</a>
    <div id="question2" style="display:none; margin:0px;">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle2('question3', this);">Question</a>
    <div id="question3" style="display:none; margin:0px;">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</li>
```

Note that these divs already have expanding hidden content in them.​

Now, lots of questions are being generated, I am at a point where I need to keep a restricted list that can expand with the rest of the divs when clicked or automatically (a la google images or twitter).

Is there any way I can limit the amount, and "expand" the list to show the rest of the list?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure on exactly what you want to do, please rewrite.

Comment: It's best explained when you click the jsfiddle link, and imagine there are 20 of the resulting "Questions" that I need to limit

Comment: What do you mean by limit? You only want ie 3 of them only to be expandable?

Comment: For example, 15 questions, 5 show, then click "more" and see 5 more, and click again and see 5 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d33zC/7/) with lots of changes, see comments for explanations. The main points are

1. Added classes everywhere
2. Added a "See More" `<li>` at the end
3. Looped over each `<ul>` (given class *questions*) then `<li>` (given class *qn*) to set it up
4. Used event listeners

It is all done in native JavaScript (no jQuery required). The main bit of the JavaScript is as follows

```
window.addEventListener('load',function load(){
    var n_shown_at_start = 3,
        n_more_displayed_on_click = 3;

    var qs = document.querySelectorAll('.questions'),
        qn, sm, i = qs.length, j;
    while( --i >= 0 ){ // loop over all questions
        sm = qs[i].querySelector('.see_more'); // get see more entry
        qn = qs[i].querySelectorAll('.qn'); // get question <li>s
        j = qn.length;
        while( --j >= 0 ){
            qn[j]
                .querySelector('.qn_vis') // <a>
                .addEventListener('click', function click(){ // make click display question
                qn_toggle(this);
                return false; // no action
            }, true);
            if(sm) // if there is a see more button, hide some questions
                qn[j].style.display = (j < n_shown_at_start ? '' : 'none');
        }
        if(sm){ // if there is a see more button, set it up
            sm.qs = qs[i];
            sm.start = n_shown_at_start;
            sm.lim = n_more_displayed_on_click;
            sm.addEventListener('click', function click(){
                var qn = this.qs.getElementsByClassName('qn'), q,
                    i = this.start, j = i + this.lim;
                this.start = j + 1;
                while(i < j && (q = qn[i++])){ // loop over questions
                    q.style.display = 'block';
                }
                if(!q || !qn[i]){ // if we reached the end
                    this.textContent = 'No More';
                }
            }, false);
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

Wrap the excess ones in a hidden DIV and show it when the Show All button is clicked

http://jsfiddle.net/vAZFv/2/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle2('question', this);">Question</a>
        <div id="question" style="display:none; margin:0px;">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle2('question2', this);">Question</a>
        <div id="question2" style="display:none; margin:0px;">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle2('question3', this);">Question</a>
        <div id="question3" style="display:none; margin:0px;">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <div  id="hiddenOnes">
          <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle2('question3', this);">Question11</a>
        <div id="question3" style="display:none; margin:0px;">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle2('question3', this);">Question11</a>
        <div id="question3" style="display:none; margin:0px;">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle2('question3', this);">Question11</a>
        <div id="question3" style="display:none; margin:0px;">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </li>

    </div>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="showAllBtn" value="Show all">​
```

**JS:**

```
function toggle2(id, link) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == '') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        e.style.display = '';
    }
}
$(function() {
    $("#hiddenOnes").hide();
    $("#showAllBtn").click(function() {
        $("#hiddenOnes").show();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Almost! Thankyou! As there will be much, much more of these, can this be expanded gradually? say 5 at a time?

Comment: Well,if thats the case I would fetch the next sets from the server using AJAX each time the button is clicked. Else your initial page load is gonna get very slow if you're planning on fetching 1000s of questions initially... If this option is not suitable,let me know, I can help you write a client-stepped version..

Comment: i have added another answer, this should solve your problem. Please mark the answer as accepted if you dont have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vZnJb/3/

First, hide all `li`'s by adding `style="display:none;"` like you already do for your div's. Then, after pressing a button or clicking a link, you iterate over all `li`'s with `document.getElementsByTagName("li");`, removing this style for a certain amount of them.

**Js code:**

```
var shown = 1;
var expand_per = 1;

function expand() {
    shown += expand_per;
    var allLists = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    i = 0;
    while (i < shown) {
        if (allLists[i] === undefined) {
            break;
        }
        if (allLists[i].style.display == 'none') {
            allLists[i].style.display = '';
        }
        i++
    }
}​
```

Edit: Of course, in a real life situation, you would fetch all questions from a database, as mentioned by Sajjan Sarkar.

Comment: Other content is shown with different id's (not questions) in the same list, would they need to be incremented to work with this?

Comment: Since you're showing or hiding list items regardless of their id, you can add anything within these `li`'s, and it'll follow the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which does everything you ask for.

**JS FIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/erRCy/

**HTML:**

```
 <ul class="topnav">
    <li>Question</li>

    <li>Question</li>

    <li>Question</li>

    <li>Question11</li>

    <li>Question11</li>

    <li>Question11</li>

    <li>Question11</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="showAllBtn" value="Show all">
```

CSS:

```
.visible{
 display:block;   
}

.invisible{
 display:none;   
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
    // Make all LIs under the UL(with class=topnav) invisible
    $("ul.topnav > li").addClass('invisible');

    // when the button is clicked
    $("#showAllBtn").click(function() {
        var gITEMS_PER_SET = 2; // set the no of items you want to show per set
        //get next set of LIs which are invisible and make them visible
        $("ul.topnav > li.invisible").slice(0, gITEMS_PER_SET).removeClass('invisible').addClass('visible');

    });
    // simulate the button click to show the initial set when page loads
    $("#showAllBtn").click();​
<script>
​
```